# A question about publishing a small library of russian ambiences/sounds

Tags: field-recording, selling

**UPD**: thanks to everyone, the question is closed. The library is published on my website, you'll find the full info here: [Urban Russia sound library](http://lesser-vibes.com/sound.html)

**UPD 2**: updated the library with new material (24/09/2014).

I'm from Russia. I've been recording various ambiences and sounds of Saint-Petersburg and Moscow for 2 years. Recently I looked through my collection and decided that it has enough audio material to be shared. I'd like to sell it for a small price, but I'm not sure about it yet.

May I ask you, a fellow sound editor or recordist, would you be interested in my collection? If true, what price would be reasonable for you?

The collection includes recordings of:

1. elevators
2. hotel lobbies
3. international conference (crowds)
4. streets and parks (including historical places like the Red Square or Nevskiy Avenue).
5. moscow monorail
6. subways
7. trains and train stations
8. shores (surf waves)
9. fireworks (New Year Celebration)
10. airport, bank office, food court, game center ambiences
11. museums (Hermitage, Kazan's Cathedral)
12. suburban electric train.
13. washrooms.

Total: 6h 40m, 7953mb.
Recorded with Zoom H4n, 44/96 kHz, 24 bit, stereo.

I created a brief mix and uploaded it on SoundCloud for your evaluation of the sound quality.

Comment: Fantastic!  On my purchase list.

Answer (score 1):

The locations look interesting, but the gear is pretty basic looking.

I personally value these things based on how they sound though, so to some degree its difficult to say what they're worth without hearing a demo.

Comment: I agree, some sort of audible demo would be helpful, yet I feel it would also be needed even with good gear.  Good gear doesn't always guarantee great recordings and vice versa.

Comment: I created a brief mix and uploaded it on SoundCloud for your evaluation of the sound quality. https://soundcloud.com/vibe-crc/ambiences-and-sounds-of-russia

Comment: Those sound quite good, I would certainly invest - especially since I've hardly found anything of substance from Russia.  What sort of lengths are the ambiences.  In the 3-5 min range or longer?  I gather they've been fully vetted/QCed (not just the raw files?

Comment: agreed - nice sounding stuff!  4 hours of stuff is probably worth a fair amount.  I'd charge at least $50 USD - probably more.  $80-95 would seem entirely fair as well.

Comment: I concur, my thoughts were somewhere within the 75-100 range. Although I also believe the length/usability is important too. The longer the recordings (and higher the fidelity), the higher the price they can command.  Although being 'found' ambiences the fidelity isn't quite so much an issue if at least 48k, 44k minimum.

Comment: @Stavrosound the length of the recordings varies from 30-40 seconds to 6-8 minutes. Sometimes I recorded several 1-2 minutes cues in a location due to being noticed by officials who are very suspicious of any unusual activity. The files are mostly RAW to give full freedom of manipulation to a person who would use them. I'll just clean them of unnecessary sounds and noises.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I'll add some new material to the library first and then I'll start preparing it for publishing.

Comment: @Serge ah, nice!  If you're open to a suggestion, maybe on those ones which you had to keep cutting, maybe string them together when mastering as one?  Assuming the POV and levels didn't change.  It'll ne easier for FX editors to deal with.

Comment: @Stavrosound no problem, I'll do this.

Comment: I'm in the process of doing exactly the same thing but with a Spanish city - some great information and advice  from @Stavrosound and Rene. Some really cool sounds in your Russian library - all the best with it.

Comment: The library is up. http://lesser-vibes.com/sound.html